# Insert some lines before a specific line with sed

Tags: sed, xml

I've the following file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

and I've to add the following lines:

```
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
```

before the closing tag /fontconfig>. I'm not sure that it's always on 7th line, so I must look for it as a string. I've some troubles in these strings with <> and / ... How can I solve with sed? thanx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `sed`, `awk` and alike for parsing XML/HMTL data - it'll never come to robust and scalable result. Use a proper XML/HTML processors.
The right way with **`xmlstarlet`** tool:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s '//fontconfig' -t elem -n 'dir' -v '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local' \
-s '//fontconfig' -t elem -n 'dir' -v '/usr/local/share/fonts' input.xml
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

---

To modify/edit the file *in-place* - add `-L` option: `xmlstarlet ed -L ....`

---

For more details type: `xmlstarlet ed --help`

Comment: Thanx, it works very nice. It's the first time I meet xmlstartlet...

Comment: @user41063, you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can overcome the issues of `/` in the pattern text by using a different delimiter such as `#` e.g.

```
sed '\#^</fontconfig>#i\
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local</dir>\
  <dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
' file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
</fontconfig>
```